# Slow Zoom and Interface with Firemonkey TeeChart

Tags: firemonkey, teechart

I am creating an Firemonkey (FMX) interface that includes several TChart components in order to display data with number of points from 1,000,000 to 10,000,000 points (C++ builder 10.4). The curves are displayed quickly by following the advice given in Steema's note “*Real-Time Charting in TeeChart*”. However, 2 problems arise:

1. Even with a number of points equal to 1,000,000, successive zooms slow down the interface enormously (beyond 3 zooms, this becomes quite painful for the user).
2. When the number of points is high, the interface becomes very slow and so interactions with the TChart are no longer smooth.

I have tested changing many parameters of the TChart or of the TFastLineSeries but without success. I also tested by modifying the global display variables "*GlobalUseGPUCanvas*" and "*GlobalUseDirect2D*" without being able to observe any improvement. Also, if I compare with TChart VCL, the display of the curves is a little slower but interactions like the zoomming are instantaneous and do not seem to slow down the interface (same behavior for the number of points) as in the case of the FMX.

Do you have any idea on how to solve these 2 problems?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you saying you want to display 1 - 10 million data points on a display of 500 - 2000 pixels? Did you consider filtering your source data to an amount that can be displayed?

Comment: I understood that the "Draw all points" option of TFastLineSeries is there to avoid drawing data that will share the same pixel. So I use this option to overcome the problem you point. But still, with the same number of points, the problem of slow interactions like zooming and slowing down the program is there on FMX TChart and not on VCL TChart. So I think the problem is not with the number of points.

Comment: Filter out all the points you don't need before you even give them to TChart. You don't want TChart to spend time figuring out whether this pixel has already been drawn or not.

Comment: I know this can improve the drawing time speed. But my problem is not the number of points. To give exact values, plotting 10 millions points takes me around 0.6 seconds, which fast for this amount of points. One of the problem is with successive zooming : First zoom takes 0.641602 secs to be done. The second takes 2.071727 secs and the third one takes 9.740854 secs. How can this be ?

Comment: The original chart is 500x1000 pixels. Could be when you zoom 2x the underlying graph is expanding by that 2x. TChart now has a graph size of 1000x2000 pixels. Because it still has to hold onto those 1 million points. You may have to filter down the points to only the ones that would show in a zoomed window. Doesn't TChart do this automatically? It probably does, but it takes time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to remove all points that can not be shown in a zoom to see if it fix the problem.